# Edit made to one tab reflected in another

Tags: google-apps-script

I have one master tab, which I have copied and have stored elsewhere. Is it possible to have any changes made in the master tab reflected in the copy?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But not that trivial to do.

Comment: Look at [this](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are referring to sheets within a Google Spreadsheet:

As stated by others, the easiest thing to do is use the [Sheets function IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en).  This function links one region of a sheet to another -- the source sheet can even be in a different spreadsheet, as long as the user has permission to view that sheet.

If you want to use Apps Script instead, then you will need to write a function to read the data from the source sheet and copy it to the target. Once you have that working, you can set up a time-trigger to copy over the data at regular intervals, an installable trigger to copy the data over when the target spreadsheet is opened, and/or a menu control so that users can trigger the data sync manually.